# Hi, I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I want to install an older version of gcc -gcc-7

Tags: package-management, gcc

**which gcc** gives - /usr/bin/gcc

**gcc version** shows - gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

**update-alternatives --query gcc** gives - no alternatives for gcc

**sudo apt-get install g++-7** gives - Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package g++-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'g++-7' has no installation candidate

**sudo apt install build-essential sudo apt -y install gcc-7 g++-7** gives - Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package g++-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package gcc-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package install
E: Package 'gcc-7' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-7' has no installation candidate

**sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 7** gives - update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc-7 doesn't exist

**sudo update-alternatives --config gcc** gives - update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc

Comment: The gcc-7 package still exists in Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa).

Comment: Install it if you must, but do not even think of using update-alternatives to change the system-wide gcc default -- a sure way to break things.  Do you really need an old gcc?

Comment: what makes you believe you need it?

Comment: I need it for installing StaMPS. The src code in StaMPS supports gcc-7 only .